# Having trouble with methods for Vimeo's new API to get url of files

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I try to get the the data of the field **"files"** with **"quality"** with the value "hd". I read about the endpoints and I try to make a request with thee values of this fields.

My problem is I can't obtain the value of the field **"files"** because is a vector. How is the way to pass this like an endpoint?.

The resource of research is the follow: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints.

Actually with my code only I can obtein the principal fields but I can't acces to the fileds compound with others.

```
$client_id = "XXX"; 
$client_secret= "XXX"; 
$access_token = "XXX" ;
$lib = new Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret, $access_token); 
$response = $lib->request("/videos/videoID")
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the `request` method will always be an associative array. This associative array will contain three values

- **body**: An associative array containing the full json response
- **headers**: An associative array of response headers
- **status**: The HTTP status code (see http://httpstatus.es for a detailed list)

To access the files array specifically, you would use the following code:

`$response['body']['files']`

This will contain an array of file objects for you to loop through.

```
foreach ($response['body']['files'] as $file) {
    // use a $file
}
```

**NOTE**: Only PRO members have access to video files, and even then only to their own files.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Your solution did not work.

Comment: I even print the whole thing as JSON and nothing says body or files anywhere. I put $fields=name,files and it gives name but no files.

Comment: I spoke with JeremyF in another ticket. For anyone still encountering problems, you now need the video_files scope to see the files key. If that doesn't resolve your issue please contact Vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact